# ReactJS - Return a component from innerHtml function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to return a component through the JS `innerHTML()` function? With the code below, it is returning on the browser screen:
`[object Object]`

```
document.getElementById("threeline-icon").innerHTML =
        `${<ThreelineIcon />}`
        ;
    }
```

**Component Code:**

```
import React from 'react'

const ThreelineIcon = () => {
  return ( 
    <div>
    <span className="top"></span>
    <span className="middle"></span>
    <span className="bottom"></span>     
    </div>
  )
}

export default ThreelineIcon
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `renderToString` method used by server side rendering to convert a React component into HTML. But please keep in mind that this works only if your Component is static, I mean any events or lifecycle methods (except `componentWillMount`) will not work.

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
document.getElementById("threeline-icon").innerHTML =
    ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<ThreelineIcon />);
```

Comment: What changes needed for events and lifecycle methods to work?

Comment: I have never tried it but i think hydrating the dom with ThreelineIcon Component, after inserting the static html might work. In theory that's how server side rendering works

Comment: Hi, I think these changes needed. Please let me know I'm doing right. https://gist.github.com/sagar-gavhane/406cb992d1857cfaa3308d8a253e6a9d and codesandbox app: https://codesandbox.io/embed/pedantic-monad-wf2b9?fontsize=14

Comment: @SagarGavhane Yes that's perfect

Answer (score 1):

You can’t actually directly access a dom element using JavaScript and set it to a react component. You have to use ReactDOM

Comment: @mohanRamalibgam
Could you please show me a sample code? to solve this problem?

Comment: @mohanRamalibgam I want to call this component after a conditional from js

Answer (score 1):

You can set flag to display your component . When your flag was true you display ThreelineIcon component by default it set false.
Like :

```
class Demo extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {flag:false}
}
.
    somefunction = (value) => {
        this.setState({ flag: !this.state.flag });
    }
.
  render() {
        return(
        .
<div>{this.state.flag && <ThreelineIcon />}</div>
        .
      }
}
```

Your Component Code:

```
import React from 'react'

const ThreelineIcon = () => {
  return ( 
    <div>
    <span className="top"></span>
    <span className="middle"></span>
    <span className="bottom"></span>     
    </div>
  )
}

export default ThreelineIcon
```